# VNCSharp Pass Static Password

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a simple `Win Forms` App which displays multiple `VNC` sessions in one grid format. The password for each `VNC` Server is the same, I am attempting to store the password as a string and call it from each `VNCSharp Connection`.

My current solution is giving me a 'non-invocable member SecurePass.pass cannot be used like a method'. What is the best way around this issue?

```
namespace AutomatedGateViewer
{
    public class SecurePassword
    {
        public static string pass = "P455W0rD";
    }

    public partial class AGSV : Form
    {
        public AGSV()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            Kiosk1VNC.GetPassword = new AuthenticateDelegate(SecurePassword.pass());
            Kiosk1VNC.Connect("172.168.110.90");

            Kiosk2VNC.GetPassword = new AuthenticateDelegate(SecurePassword.pass());
            Kiosk2VNC.Connect("172.168.110.99");    
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @RobertBaron I have edited my question with more info.

Comment: `SecurePassword.pass` isn't a method, like the error message indicates.  So remove the parenthesis.

Comment: True, then I get Method Name expected as my error. I believe I need to do a labdaexpression but I cannot get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in a delegate to the `GetPassword` property.  The [signature of that delegate](https://github.com/humphd/VncSharp/blob/5a8b71e3150a2cba67661f6db649c6fe859d1ccf/VncSharp/RemoteDesktop.cs#L46) is:

```
string AuthenticateDelegate();
```

So, we need a lambda expression that accepts no parameters and returns a string.  Easy enough:

```
Kiosk1VNC.GetPassword = new AuthenticateDelegate(() => SecurePassword.pass);
```

That might not work (I don't have a VS window up).  If not, use this instead:

```
Kiosk1VNC.GetPassword = () => SecurePassword.pass;
```

Comment: Perfect. I was just about to edit my original question. It makes complete sense now. Many Thanks